# React unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, sinon

I am trying to write test cases of react component in Mocha + Enzyme. I have used Sinon to spy document elements.

In a react component method i have below statement, where trying to add a value for Select element on Button click event.

```
handleClick(e){
e.preventDefault();
if(e.target.value!='select')
    this.setState({
      selectedValue: e.target.value
    })
else         
 document.getElementsByName("foodSelector")[0].value="select";
}
```

So i tried mocking this method as below using Mocha,

```
describe('(Container) ReactContainer', () => {
    beforeEach(function(){
        wrapper = shallow(<SelectContainer/>);  
    })
    it('should trigger change event when policy dropdown is clicked', function(){
        const selectElt = wrapper.find('#foodSelector');
        selectElt.simulate('change', { preventDefault() {}, target: { value: 'TestingValue' } });       
        selectElt.simulate('change', { preventDefault() {}, target: { value: 'select' } });     
    }); 
});
```

I am getting an error as 'TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined', so can anyone help me on how to mock the document.getElementById?

I tried using sinon as below,

```
var selectElt = document.createElement('select');
selectElt.id = 'foodSelector';
var f = sinon.stub(document, 'getElementById').withArgs('foodSelector').returns(selectElt);
expect(f.value).to.be.equal('select');
```

Even then i am getting the same error as below,

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

Comment: I think we should not use `document.getElementsByName` and instead use `ReactDOM` to get the elements. It should be easier to test it.

Comment: Why use the DOM to change the select value? why not: `this.setState({ selectedValue: 'select' }); ? This this the React way of doing things.